# C# .NET 7.0 Calling a class with DI. How ILogger can be passed?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, lazy-loading, ilogger

I have this class with DI :

```cs
public class WeatherForecastService : IWeatherForecastService
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastService> logger;

        public WeatherForecastService(
            HttpClient httpClient,
            ILogger<WeatherForecastService> logger)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

    public async ValueTask<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetWeatherForecasts()
    {
        WeatherForecast[] forecasts = 
            await this.httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>(
                "sample-data/weather.json");
        return forecasts.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

And I need to call this class like :

```cs
public class LazyLoadedWeatherForecastService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider services;

    public LazyLoadedWeatherForecastService(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        this.services = services;
    }

    public IWeatherForecastService Create()
    {
        HttpClient http = this.services.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
        return new WeatherForecastService(http, ???????);
    }
}
```

You see the `??????`.  What I have to put there to call it correctly?

Comment: Why don't you call `this.services.GetRequiredService<IWeatherForecastService>()`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public IWeatherForecastService Create()
            {
              HttpClient http = this.services.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
              var logger = this.services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<WeatherForecastService>>();
              return new WeatherForecastService(http, logger);
            }
```